# Seek to "0" or use rewind method?

Tags: ruby, file

If I wish to return to the start of a file, is it better to use

```
f.seek(0)
```

or

```
f.rewind
```

for the example "f" file handle? Or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not quite the same thing so *better* depends on intent. [`seek`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-seek) just moves the current offset around:

> **seek(amount, whence=IO::SEEK_SET) → 0**
>
> Seeks to a given offset *anInteger* in the stream according to the value of *whence*: ...

but [`rewind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-rewind) also adjusts [`lineno`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-lineno):

> **rewind → 0**
>
> Positions *ios* to the beginning of input, resetting *lineno* to zero.

so `f.rewind` is more or less the same as:

```
f.seek(0)
f.lineno = 0
```

If you look at the MRI C implementation, you'll see that `rewind` is implemented just like that but in C rather than Ruby.

So if you're working with binary data (i.e. no line numbers) or you're sure you don't care about line numbers, then `f.seek(0)` and `f.rewind` are functionally equivalent.

I'd tend to use `rewind` because it directly expresses my intent.